# Issues with escaping a NSString

Tags: ios7, nsstring, nsurl

I want to escape an NSString to use in NSURL. Here the line...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/2013/12/sample.jpg" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUFT8StringEncoding];
```

But I get an error:

> No known class method for selector: "URLWithString:string By Adding
>   Percent Escape Using Encodin"

Could you figured out what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You mean surely:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/2013/12/sample.jpg" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And take care of `NSUFT8StringEncoding` vs `NSUTF8StringEncoding` :)